# How can I attach a newly created file to the model

Tags: python, django, watermark, video-watermarking

The user adds a video and a watermark is automatically applied to the video. It turns out to process the user's video and **put a watermark**, but I don't know **how to attach this video to the model, so that later this video with a watermark would be displayed on the site**. Just attach obj.video_uploaded = final_ to the model - it doesn't work, writes the error object has no attribute '_committed'
model.py

```
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photo/%Y/%m/%d')
    video_uploaded = models.FileField(upload_to='video/%Y/%m/%d',blank=True,null=True)
```

views.py

```
def add_video(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = VideoUploaderForm(
            data=request.POST,
            files=request.FILES,
        )
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            vid = request.FILES['video_uploaded']
            clip = VideoFileClip(vid.temporary_file_path())
            # watermark
            video = VideoFileClip(clip.filename)
            logo = (ImageClip('faiklogo.png')
                    .set_duration(video.duration)
                    .resize(height=50)
                    .margin(right=8, top=8, opacity=0)
                    .set_pos(("center", "bottom")))
            final_ = CompositeVideoClip([video, logo])
            final_.write_videofile('media/video/videwithwatermark.mp4')
            obj.save()
    else:
        form=VideoUploaderForm()
    return render(request, 'firstapp/add_video.html', {"foenter code hererm": form})
```

form.py

```
class VideoUploaderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

When saving to a FileField, a an instance of FieldFile will let you save it using instance.save(file_name,file_contents), where contents has to be an instance of *django.core.files.File* or *django.core.files.base.ContentFile*
try:

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

obj.video_uploaded.save(final_.name, ContentFile(final_.read()))
```

Comment: 'CompositeVideoClip' object has no attribute 'read', 'CompositeVideoClip' object has no attribute 'name'